# Here Document to run shell command with partial substitution

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'd like to write such script:

```
FileList="/tmp /"
ssh user@host <<EOF
for file in $FileList
do
df -h $file
done
EOF
```

But $file is substitued. I need $FileList being substitued but not $file.

Comment: So escape `$`. `\$file`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes right, Thanks Kamil Cuk, it works:

```
    FileList="/tmp /"
    ssh user@host <<EOF
    for file in $FileList
    do
    echo "checking \$file"
    df -h \$file
    done
    EOF
```